# How to draw a line between each image view in each Listview item

Tags: android, listview, drawing

I'd like to create the following design as attached link.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx1jK.jpg

Now, I'm using list view but I cannot figure out how to draw the white to connect between each bullet-liked icon in each list item together.

Would someone give me any idea how ? Should I use a treeview ?
The example working code would be enough. I can apply to my code.

Thanks,
Thanachao

Comment: What are you able to do so far? With the description of what you are able to do now, more people might help

Comment: What I have left to do is to draw the line to connect between each plus image view.

Comment: There is a generic View that you can customize to make a line, I suggest you put that first and put the image view on top of it.

Comment: would you please give me some example ?

Comment: @Thanachao edit your list item layout and add a View below the plus icon with width and height needed for line. This would repeat in each row and show as connected from plus to icon. Show you list item layout to help further.

Comment: Ok! guys, I will get back as soon as I have finished that part first.

Comment: @AlokNair please post your suggestion as an answer. I will accept your solution.

Comment: @Thanachao Glad that it helped. Have posted the suggestion as answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your list item layout and add a View below the plus icon with width and height needed for line. This would repeat in each row and show as connected from plus to icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create your listview item layout contain a line and the icon you want then you will simply hide the divider (line) between the items by using

```
android:divider="@null"
```

This should simply create the design